# Can't view contacts group page DataTables warning due to an sql syntax error

Tags: error

On viewing my contacts group page I am getting an error.

The mysql audit log shows that the failing query is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache397 (SELECT
 25           AS group_id,
 contact_a.id AS id
FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN
  civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-(23` ON (
 contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact-(23`.contact_id
AND `civicrm_group_contact-(23`.status IN
    (\'Added\'))   LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact `civicrm_group_contact-19` ON (contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact-19`.contact_id AND `civicrm_group_contact-19`.status IN (\'Added\'))   LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_23,24,25` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_23,24,25`.contact_id    LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_24)` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_24)`.contact_id   WHERE  (  (  ( ( `civicrm_group_contact-19`.group_id = 19  ) OR  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_23,24,25`.group_id IN ("23", "24", "25") )  )  AND  ( ( `civicrm_group_contact-(23`.group_id NOT IN ( (23 )  ) OR  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_24)`.group_id
```

The quotes look a bit garbled? Any ideas?

I'm not sure anything changed except for the normal upgrades and the volunteers module being installed.

4.7.25 of CiviCRM.

Comment: What messages do you get in the error log?

Comment: Sql query exception. I have found out since that it is a particular group. If I view groups by 10 then I can see the first 10 and the last 10.